# puppet Evaluation Error: Cannot reassign variable

Tags: puppet

We are trying to override the the value assigned to the variable in the puppet manifest. Below is the piece of the line from puppet manifest :

```
39  $java_opts_nodeconfig_extra = '-XX:+ScavengeBeforeFullGC -verbose:gc'
40
41  if $jdk_version =~ /^1.8\.\d+\_/ {
42    $java_opts_nodeconfig_extra = "-XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCDetails ${java_opts_nodeconfig_extra}"
43  }
```

And puppet script fails with below error, my use case is if the JDK version is 1.8.x, then override the value and assign to the same variable otherwise the original value assigned to the variable.

```
Error: Evaluation Error: Error while evaluating a Resource Statement, Evaluation Error: Cannot reassign variable '$java_opts_snippet_nodeconfig_extra' (file:/puppet/modules/acme/manifests/acme_manager.pp, line: 42, column: 41)
```

How do we solve this ?

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, based on this `https://codeburst.io/puppet-code-by-example-part-2-b1099b4ff9a1`, looks like we cannot reassign. So , we used other way by means of using "Case" statement.

Comment: Would be useful if you detailed the solution you implemented with Case